# How to grant privilege to a row in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm just start learning about Oracle database. I want to ask that how can I grant privilege to a row. For example: employee A just can read, update info about him and he can't read info about employee B or others
Here is my table Employee

```
     create table Employee(
        Emp_ID varchar2(20),
        Emp_Name varchar2(255),
        primary key(Emp_ID)
     )
```

Comment: I dont think its possible at table level. You can create a View instead and grant access on a view containing an employee's info.

Comment: You would have to develop a view by which the table would be queried.  Or more advanced, implement Virtual Private Database (VPD).  But before you implement any technical solutions, you need to think through your actual business case.  Why would just any employee have access at all, that he should be restricted to seeing only his own data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a Data_Owner field to the table populated by the USER function. Don't allow direct access to the table. All access is through a view that exposes only those rows matching the USER value of whoever queries the view. Use the USER function to control the DML.

Here is a sample. Test to see if it meets your needs

```
create view Sample as
select col_1, col_2, col3
from   Sample_Table
where  Data_Owner = USER;
```